# Java cloning arrays as parameters in a constructor

Tags: java, list, recursion, shallow-copy

As stated in my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20888629/all-possible-paths), I am attempting to write a game AI. Currently, I have a loop which iterates through the neighbors of a cell, generating a list of possible moves. At some point in this loop (which is heavily recursive), I declare a new `DotMove` object which stores the information for that particular move. This move is then appended to an ever growing list of moves.

Each move has a ordered list of dots which are considered it's "path".

Unfortunately, these `DotMove` objects do not seem to hold the references to the paths correctly. Specifically, when I go to print the paths of the `DotMove` objects which are generated, the paths come back as only one item long. (The paths *should*  be several items long, and vary as the list prints out.)

```
List<Edge> e = getEdgesAt(p, con);
ArrayList<DotMove> moveList = new ArrayList<DotMove>();

for (Edge edge : e) {
    if (visited.add(edge)) {
        Point next = edge.getNextPoint(p);
        path.add(next);
        findMovesAtPointHelper(next, path, connected, visited);
        moveList.add(new DotMove(path, this));
    }
}
path.remove(path.size() - 1);
return moveList;
```

Which yields the following output:

```
r r b g r g r g 
r r b g y r r b 
b r b g b r r p 
b r b b g r r r 
b r b r r r b r 
r b b p r p b b 
p r y y g g b b 
p y r b y p b r 

[(0, 0)]
[(0, 1)]
[(1, 0)]
[(1, 1)]
[(1, 2)]
[(1, 2)]
[(1, 2)]
```

However, when I replace the `moveList.add(...)` with a statement that prints the path at that time, I get the following (correct) output:

```
r r b g r g r g 
r r b g y r r b 
b r b g b r r p 
b r b b g r r r 
b r b r r r b r 
r b b p r p b b 
p r y y g g b b 
p y r b y p b r 

[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1)]
[(0, 0)]
```

I believe this discrepancy is caused by my DotMove constructor, and the Path constructor which it calls. The two have been included here for reference.

```
public DotMove(ArrayList<Point> path, BoardModel boardModel) {
    this.path = new Path(path);
    this.cleared = path;
    this.score = path.size();
}

public Path(List<Point> path){
    this.path = new ArrayList<Point>(path);
}
```

It appears that the `Path()` constructor is retaining a reference to the entire list, rather than making a shallow copy of the list. This would explain the why the lists inside the `DotMove` objects are shorter, because the move-finding algorithm relies on removing items from the end of a list as it traverses the board. The `DotMove` objects are meant to store "snapshots" of this list, not references to the list itself.

How can I create shallow copies of this list correctly?

Comment: Have a look at static method `copy` of `java.util.Collections` class - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#copy(java.util.List, java.util.List).

Comment: I've just tried this, and it gives me lists with zero elements in them.

Comment: Seems like you need to create `ArrayList` with **the same size** first. `new ArrayList<Point>(path.size);`

Comment: It baffles me why your original approach didn't work though.  Are you sure you pinpointed the right spot to fix?

Comment: I did create a destination array of the appropriate size first, and still no luck. I am also baffled. I'm currently looking to see if there is a bug elsewhere

Comment: Have you tried to go step-by-step under debugger and examine all the intermediate values.

Answer (score 1):

After much toil, the bug was located here:

```
ArrayList<DotMove> moveList = new ArrayList<DotMove>();
```

This created a new `moveList` at every recursion of the `findMovesAtPointHelper` method. This caused the other methods to be lost at every iteration.

For reference, here is a new list of moves, sorted by length, then by score (the last number is a hash which identifies functionally equivalent moves.):

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5 
0 r r b g b r 
1 r r b r r r 
2 b r b y y b 
3 b g b y b b 
4 b y b p b b 
5 y b r b y b 

Top 5 moves: 
 17 Loop [(4, 3), (4, 4), (5, 4), (5, 3), (4, 3)] -86374027
 17 Loop [(4, 4), (4, 3), (5, 3), (5, 4), (4, 4)] -86374027
 17 Loop [(5, 3), (4, 3), (4, 4), (5, 4), (5, 3)] -86374027
 17 Loop [(5, 4), (4, 4), (4, 3), (5, 3), (5, 4)] -86374027
 17 Loop [(5, 2), (5, 3), (4, 3), (4, 4), (5, 4), (5, 3)] -86374027

Bottom 5 moves: 
  2      [(5, 5), (5, 4)] -739973680
  2      [(5, 4), (4, 4)] -1399527984
  2      [(5, 3), (4, 3)] 831841744
  2      [(4, 4), (4, 3)] 1423500752
  2      [(5, 2), (5, 3)] 2075715024

Pre-uniquify: 105
Post-uniquify: 105
All 105 moves: 
 17 Loop [(4, 3), (4, 4), (5, 4), (5, 3), (4, 3)] -86374027
 17 Loop [(4, 4), (4, 3), (5, 3), (5, 4), (4, 4)] -86374027
 17 Loop [(5, 3), (4, 3), (4, 4), (5, 4), (5, 3)] -86374027
 17 Loop [(5, 4), (4, 4), (4, 3), (5, 3), (5, 4)] -86374027
 17 Loop [(5, 2), (5, 3), (4, 3), (4, 4), (5, 4), (5, 3)] -86374027
 17 Loop [(5, 3), (4, 3), (4, 4), (5, 4), (5, 3), (5, 2)] -86374027
 17 Loop [(5, 4), (4, 4), (4, 3), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5)] -86374027
 17 Loop [(5, 5), (5, 4), (4, 4), (4, 3), (5, 3), (5, 4)] -86374027
 10 Loop [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0), (0, 0)] -834522920
 10 Loop [(0, 1), (0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1)] -834522920
 10 Loop [(1, 0), (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0)] -834522920
 10 Loop [(1, 1), (0, 1), (0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1)] -834522920
 10 Loop [(1, 1), (0, 1), (0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)] -834522920
 10 Loop [(1, 2), (1, 1), (0, 1), (0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1)] -834522920
  6      [(5, 2), (5, 3), (4, 3), (4, 4), (5, 4), (5, 5)] 1195567956
  6      [(5, 5), (5, 4), (4, 4), (4, 3), (5, 3), (5, 2)] 1195567956
  5      [(0, 1), (0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)] -1697404439

...
```